# get_html_translation_table expects at most 2 parameters, 3 given

Tags: php

The server is running with **PHP 5.2.17**, and I am trying to run get_html_translation_table() with three arguments. Here is how I invoke the function:

```
$text = get_html_translation_table(HTML_ENTITIES, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
```

I am getting a warning message saying

> get_html_translation_table expects at most 2 parameters, 3 given
>   (filename and line number).

Per [PHP Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-html-translation-table.php#refsect1-function.get-html-translation-table-changelog), the third argument is supported **after PHP 5.3.4,** but adding the third argument is the only way I can think of to encode the array returned in "UTF-8". (It works despite the ugly warning message.)

I need get_html_translation_table() to create a function that encode **all html special characters and spaces**, and the following function just won't work without the third argument.

```
/**
 * Trying to encoding all html special characters, including nl2br()
 * @param string  $original
 * @return string
 */
function ecode_html_sp_chars($original) {
    $table = get_html_translation_table(HTML_ENTITIES, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
    $table[' '] = '&nbsp;';
    $encoded = strtr($original, $table);
    return nl2br($encoded);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options: change your php version or use the htmlentities function. In htmlentities the encoding parameter was added in 4.1.

Example:

```
function ecode_html_sp_chars($original) {
    $encoded = htmlentities($original, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
    $encoded = str_replace(' ', '&nbsp;', $encoded);
    return nl2br($encoded);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that is probably the way I should go.